# How can i get the histogram in a region of a picture using EMGU or OpenCv?

Tags: c#, opencv, histogram, emgucv

I'm trying to build a basic video tracker that tracks an object by his histogram, i have a region (rectangle) where the object is initially located. And i want to get the histogram of the image in that region. (and then to look around in the next frame for that histogram).

How can i get an histogram in a specific area as efficiently as possible ?

p.s 
I work with c# + emgu .. but if there is no solution in emgu but there is in OpenCV it will be helpful too
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recognize histograms with a specific shape in opencv / python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159493/how-to-recognize-histograms-with-a-specific-shape-in-opencv-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting [ROI](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/be373a84-4ee0-f181-665e-ba1d6d7e3e18.htm) (region of interest) and work with it?

Comment: @OopsUser did you read that doc? also look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516573/how-to-cut-a-sub-part-of-an-image-using-emgu-cv-or-opencv

Answer (score 0):

the Emgu densehistogram class has a built in mask argument.  I haven't used it but it might help.

```
hist.Calculate<Byte>(new Image<Gray, byte>[] { ImageFrame }, true, MASKGOESHERE);
```