# Reading data from scanned forms

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, ocr

I currently have a .NET 4 application that reads barcode data from scanned PDFs/Images. I need to extend this app  to read other types of data from the scanned forms. For example, one of the requirements is to check whether an input box at a particular location (X, Y) on the form is shaded/colored. I am looking for any suggestions of open source libraries that meet this requirement. Is this OCR or should I look for any image processing libraries?

Comment: That sounds like OMR (Optical Mark Recognition), not OCR.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is the best open source library for image processing, for C# there is a wrapper for OpenCV called [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Download the latest version of EmguCV. [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/files/emgucv/2.4.10/) (Download the first file)

There is a lot of tutorials available online. Here are few:

1. [Copy part of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516573/how-to-cut-a-sub-part-of-an-image-using-emgu-cv-or-opencv)
2. [How to cut a sub-part of an image using Emgu CV (or OpenCV)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516573/how-to-cut-a-sub-part-of-an-image-using-emgu-cv-or-opencv)

OCR is also the part of image processing. But you don't need it in this case.

Comment: I support this answer. But in case later down the line you need to actually read values from the form and you do need OCR, I recommend puma.net http://pumanet.codeplex.com/ it is OCR for .net languages and is pretty easy to use.

Comment: Thank you @andrew for sharing such a great library. That was not into my knowledge

Comment: everyone always pairs opencv with tessarect which is great when you use C or C++ but for c# (or other .net languages) puma is one of the only free (BSD license) libraries out there.